# C# PathGeometry equivalent in Swift

Tags: c#, objective-c, wpf, swift

Just wondering if there is any equivalent in Swift to PathGeometry, PathFigure in C#.

Working on something which would draw a path line with the collection of given Points.

Thanks,

Naresh

Comment: In Swift's stdlib, no. But there is UIBezierPath in UIKit, and you can use it with Swift.

Comment: thanks @EricD. I will give a try and update.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw polygons and poly lines over map using map box SDK. It has its own methods. In one project we used same. Check this out https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/

Comment: thanks @pushkraj. We really not looking to use any maps. We would like to draw the path with given points and save that as thumbnail.